# Change image dynamically using JQuery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

By the way I am new in JQuery!. There are three images in html page, and only one image display based one status value from SQL. I want to display one image only, for example if status = 1 show green image and if status = 2 show red image. How to do that using JQuery?

HTML Code:

```
 <div id="divGraphic" style="text-align: center; margin: auto; width: 960px; height: 540px; overflow: hidden; position: relative;">
      <img src="img/overview2.png" style="width: 960px; height: auto; margin-top: -129px;" />

      <img class="crest green" src="img/green/crest-gate.png" />
      <img class="crest red" src="img/red/crest-gate.png" />
      <img class="crest yellow" src="img/yellow/crest-gate.png" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You would want to make use of Jquery attr()

As an example

```
$("#img").attr("src","http://example.com/image.jpg");
```

This will allow you dynamically change the an images src location and accomplish what you've requested.

You can find more information about attr() at the following documentation link

> http://api.jquery.com/attr/

As for pulling the data from a SQL database.

You would want to setup some server side code to pull any specific data. And use an AJAX request to dynamically grab this information.

Jquery makes AJAX requests fairly simple and straight forward.

The server side code is really up to your choosing. Keep in mind security though, this type of work can(If not properly handled) open up some larger security holes.

Comment: but how to read status from sql in order to change an image based on status value?

Comment: what I am facing now is how to check status value in SQL, so an image can be changed using attr() in JQuery